# Bitmap.LockBits usage causing AccessViolation?

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing

I have some code that copies a `Bitmap` into a Direct3D `Texture` for rendering video.  When the system is under heavy load, I get occasional `AccessViolationException`'s on the call to `Bitmap.LockBits`.

Here is a very simple example of what happens:

```
// Get a PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb image
Bitmap bitmap24 = getVideoFrame();

// Copy into a 32bpp ARGB texture
BitmapData bitmapData = null;
try
{
    // Why am I allowed to do this?
    bitmapData = this.bitmap24.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                                        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
                                        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // Blit from bitmapData to texture32
    Texture texture32 = convertBitmapToTexture(bitmapData);
}
finally
{
    if (bitmapData != null)
        this.bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
}
```

Why am I allowed to call `Bitmap.LockBits` and pass in `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` when I know that the bitmap format is `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`?  I assume that `LockBits` must automagically expand from 3 bytes per pixel to 4.

Could the `LockBits` expansion be causing these exceptions?  Why would it only happen occasionaly?

Comment: You are looking for this problem in the wrong code.  Dealing with native code you didn't write having stability problems is difficult, slash and burn is the typical approach when you can't get good support from the vendor.  Buy another one.

Answer (score 0):

LockBits will store the bitmap in memory in whatever format you specify.

`AccessViolationException` occurs when you're accessing memory you aren't supposed to be accessing. I can think of two scenarios where this will happen:

1) You're using `ImageLockMode.ReadOnly`.. is there anywhere you're actually trying to change a value of a pixel? Perhaps try changing this to `ImageLockMode.ReadWrite` and see if that helps.

2) You've confused yourself about how big your buffer must be and you have a `Marshal.Copy` in your `convertBitmapToTexture` function that is attempting to copy past the end of your buffer.

It might be easier for you to think in terms of `int`'s instead of `byte`s when you're using 32bppArgb. That way you'll be less likely to run into any confusion.

Comment: I'm certain that nothing is written to the bitmap, and the `AccessViolation` occurs in GDI+ `LockBitsInternal` not during any copying.  Thanks for the ideas, i'll keep digging.